# Merging two rows into one header using R

Tags: r, merge, header, title, tidyverse

I have performed an experiment analysis and now I have a huge list that unfortunately has two headers in the following way:

```
Image       Nuclei                  Cell
Metadata_s  Children_Cells_Count    Intensity_IntegratedIntensityEdge_ERKStain
C4          1                       39.03921669
...         ...                     ...
```

As there are 65 rows in this document (7x Image, 35x Nuclei and 23x Cells), I would like to have an automatic way using R to merge those two columns because I need them in the same column, as follows:

```
Image_Metadata_s    Nuclei_Children_Cells_Count     Cell_Intensity_IntegratedIntensityEdge_ERKStain
C4                  1                               39.03921669
...                 ...                             ...
```

Does anybody of you know, how I could target this problem? I guess that there is a solution using the tidyverse librar, but so far I didn't find anything to solve this issue and I would be very helpful, if someone of you could help me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to `paste` the first row in header and then delete the row

```
names(df) <- paste(names(df), df[1, ], sep = "_")
df[-1,]
```

Make sure the columns are read as characters and not factors. You can change them to character by doing

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(read.table(text = "Image       Nuclei                  Cell
                 Metadata_s  Children_Cells_Count    Intensity_IntegratedIntensityEdge_ERKStain
                 C4          1                       39.03921669",header = T))

for(col in names(df))
{setnames(df,col,paste0(col,"_",df[1,get(col)]))}
df <- df[-1]

  Image_Metadata_s Nuclei_Children_Cells_Count Cell_Intensity_IntegratedIntensityEdge_ERKStain
1:               C4                           1                                     39.03921669
```